# How can I check if a file is completely written to disk?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ntfs

I'm trying to implement a safe file replacement method, which should be resistant to instant crashes, like power supply failures. I know NTFS ensures file renames are atomic, so I just write the contents to a temp file before renaming it to "commit".

The only component I'm missing is: how do I make sure that the contents of the file have been completely written to disk? I don't write the file (I only get the file name) so I can't use `FileStream.Flush(true)`.

As far as I know, NTFS doesn't protect the contents and Windows can postpone writing them for as long as it likes. If the rename happens before the contents are done, bad things can happen.

Comment: do you have direct access to the writer process's code?

Comment: you could read the file after you have written it.
If you have acces to the path then you could check byte by byte if it was written correctly or you could use a checksum.

Comment: @JMgamerZzzTM The bytes you'll got will be probably from the Windows's file cache when you read it. At least I will expect it.

Comment: @Steve The writer can be a DLL. It'll probably be running inside the same process, if that's what you mean. But I can't alter the code that creates and populates the file. I will know when the library has finished writing the file.

Comment: In .NET, the runtime should call [`FlushFileBuffers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers) if we open the file and call `Flush`. As you can see in [`FatCommonFlushBuffers`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/6c1981b8504329521343ad00f32daa847fa6083a/filesys/fastfat/flush.c#L145) in the fastfat sample driver, the flush is implemented at the level of the underlying file control block (FCB) that's referenced by all open kernel File object instances.

Comment: The [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.flush?view=netframework-4.7.2) states that "[w]hen you call the FileStream.Flush method, the operating system I/O buffer is also flushed". That means it calls `FlushFileBuffers`.

Comment: @eryksun So basically just open the file for append, flush and close? And after that the contents should be on the hard drive?

Comment: I'd verify with a breakpoint on `FlushFileBuffers` in a debugger. If it doesn't get called by the `Flush` method, then you can at least use the handle to [P/Invoke it](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FlushFileBuffers.html).